# Inner Join, Join on doesnt work as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I am trying to find recommended books for customer based on his already purchased books.
Recommendations are based on books meta keyword table.
Customer has already bought books `13` and `14` and I expect the sql query to return `3` because this is the only book has a matching `a` meta keyword with other 2 books.

To see customer purchased books you can run the below below query which returns 13, 11
`SELECT c.book FROM customers_books c WHERE c.customer = 1`

I think this line `AND bmk2.book <> bmk1.book` isnt working as expected.

Please see my sample sql here.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tovUePp2WVffXLcuaxmJ8K/5

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question to include the SQL inline, as well as the DBFiddle link. Otherwise, the question will become meaningless if the link expires in future.

Answer (score 1):

`INNER JOIN` do not work as you are expecting. `AND bmk2.book <> bmk1.book` becomes true when it tries to join book 13 and book 11 as `13<>11`. and customer can have more than one book in `customers_books` table which will create an issue in `INNER JOIN`

You need `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT distinct bmk2.book
  FROM customers_books cb
 INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk1 
   ON  bmk1.book = cb.book
 INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk2
   ON bmk2.meta_keyword = bmk1.meta_keyword
 INNER JOIN books b ON b.id = bmk2.book
 WHERE cb.customer = 1 AND b.status = 'PUBLISHED'
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customers_books cbb
                where cbb.book = bmk2.book
                  and cbb.customer = cb.customer)
```

[SQLFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69a80c2c0b2833e06677da5c814b8aff)

Comment: `INNER JOIN book_meta_keywords bmk2 ON bmk2.meta_keyword = bmk1.meta_keyword` do we need second join in this case ? and any idea to make the query bit more simple. I've heard inner select queries can be improved with joins.

Comment: book_meta_keywords table need twice in your query as one is needed to map book from customers_books and one is to map meta_keyword based on the books found using first mapping.